# I have a spring boot application with quite a simple service, repository classes defined, with db queries. But when I run it I get an error

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, maven, security

Please find the following error I am receiving.While getting the application up and running I get the following error when app starts up.  It seems like there is a problem with the insert queries and how it is trying to insert and read the data.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'screeningService' defined in file [C:\wksp\BookMyMovie-master\target\classes\com\sburgula\business\service\ScreeningService.class]: 

                    Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'screeningRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property screeningDate found for type String! Traversed path: Screening.movieName.at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1154) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1056) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:759) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866) ~[spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542) ~[spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]at com.sburgula.ReservationsApplication.main(ReservationsApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
                                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_321]
                                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_321]
                                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_321]
                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_321]
                                at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar:1.4.3.RELEASE]
                            Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'screeningRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property screeningDate found for type String! Traversed path: Screening.movieName.
                                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1589) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
                                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:554) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
                                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
                                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
                                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
                                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
                                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
                                at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:207) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
                                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1136) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
                                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1064) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
                                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
                                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
                                ... 24 common frames omitted
                            Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property screeningDate found for type String! Traversed path: Screening.movieName.
                                at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:77) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
                                at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:329) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
                                at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:309) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
                                at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:339) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
                                at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:243) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
                                at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Part.<init>(Part.java:76) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
                                at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.<init>(PartTree.java:235) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
                                at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.buildTree(PartTree.java:373) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.6.RELEASE.jar:na]
                                at  
            org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1585) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
                                ... 35 common frames omitted
```

These are my insert queries into the DB:

```
                    INSERT INTO MOVIE (MOVIE_ID,MOVIE_NAME) VALUES (1234,'Casino');
                    INSERT INTO MOVIE (MOVIE_ID,MOVIE_NAME) VALUES (2345,'Sense and Sensibility');
                    INSERT INTO MOVIE (MOVIE_ID,MOVIE_NAME) VALUES (5678,'Sabrina');
                    INSERT INTO MOVIE (MOVIE_ID,MOVIE_NAME) VALUES (4567,'Heat');
                
                INSERT INTO SCREENING (SCREENING_ID, THEATRE_ID, SCREEN_ID, MOVIE_NAME,SCREENING_DATE,SCREENING_TIME,BOOKED_TICKETS) VALUES (DEFAULT, 1,1,'Casino','2018-05-25','18:00:00', 20);
                INSERT INTO SCREENING (SCREENING_ID, THEATRE_ID, SCREEN_ID, MOVIE_NAME,SCREENING_DATE,SCREENING_TIME,BOOKED_TICKETS) VALUES (DEFAULT, 2,1,'Sense and Sensibility','2018-05-24','15:00:00',20);
                INSERT INTO SCREENING (SCREENING_ID, THEATRE_ID, SCREEN_ID, MOVIE_NAME,SCREENING_DATE,SCREENING_TIME,BOOKED_TICKETS) VALUES (DEFAULT, 3,1,'Sabrina','2018-05-23','14:00:00', 20);
                INSERT INTO SCREENING (SCREENING_ID, THEATRE_ID, SCREEN_ID, MOVIE_NAME,SCREENING_DATE,SCREENING_TIME,BOOKED_TICKETS) VALUES (DEFAULT, 4,1,'Heat','2018-05-22','16:00:00', 20);
                
                INSERT INTO TICKET (TICKET_ID, SCREENING_ID, SEAT_NUM, PRICE) VALUES (DEFAULT, 1, 100, 400);
                INSERT INTO TICKET (TICKET_ID, SCREENING_ID, SEAT_NUM, PRICE) VALUES (DEFAULT, 2, 25, 200);
                INSERT INTO TICKET (TICKET_ID, SCREENING_ID, SEAT_NUM, PRICE) VALUES (DEFAULT, 3, 50, 200);
                INSERT INTO TICKET (TICKET_ID, SCREENING_ID, SEAT_NUM, PRICE) VALUES (DEFAULT, 4, 100, 500);
```

The error it shows is:
No property screeningDate found for type String! Traversed path: Screening.movieName.
I am giving the Screening class below:

```
                package com.sburgula.data.entity;
                import javax.persistence.*;
                import java.sql.Date;
                import java.sql.Time;
                @Entity
                @Table(name = "SCREENING")
                public class Screening implements Cloneable {
                    @Id
                    @Column(name = "SCREENING_ID")
                    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
                    private long screeningId;
                    @Column(name = "THEATRE_ID")
                    private long theatreId;
                    @Column(name = "SCREEN_ID")
                    private long screenId;
                    @Column(name = "MOVIE_NAME")
                    private String movieName;
                    @Column(name = "SCREENING_DATE")
                    private java.sql.Date screeningDate;
                    @Column(name = "SCREENING_TIME")
                    private java.sql.Time screeningTime;
                    @Column(name = "BOOKED_TICKETS")
                    private int bookedTickets;    
                    public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException{
                        return super.clone();
                    }
                   public int getBookedTickets() {
                        return bookedTickets;
                    }
                    public void setBookedTickets(int bookedTickets) {
                        this.bookedTickets = bookedTickets;
                    }
                    public long getScreeningId() {
                        return screeningId;
                    }
                    public void setScreeningId(long screeningId) {
                        this.screeningId = screeningId;
                    }
                    public long getTheatreId() {
                        return theatreId;
                    }
                    public void setTheatreId(long theatreId) {
                        this.theatreId = theatreId;
                    }
                    public long getScreenId() {
                        return screenId;
                    }
                    public void setScreenId(long screenId) {
                        this.screenId = screenId;
                    }
                    public String getMovieName() {
                        return movieName;
                    }
                    public void setMovieName(String movieName) {
                        this.movieName = movieName;
                    }
                    public Date getScreeningDate() {
                        return screeningDate;
                    }
                    public void setScreeningDate(Date screeningDate) {
                        this.screeningDate = screeningDate;
                    }
                    public Time getScreeningTime() {
                        return screeningTime;
                    }
                    public void setScreeningTime(Time screeningTime) {
                        this.screeningTime = screeningTime;
                    }
                }
```

Please find the code for service class below:

```
                    package com.sburgula.business.service;
                    import java.math.BigDecimal;
                    import java.util.ArrayList;
                    import java.util.Date;
                    import java.util.HashSet;
                    import java.util.List;
                    import java.util.Set;
                    import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
                   import com.sburgula.business.domain.MovieScreening;
                    import com.sburgula.data.entity.Movie;
                    import com.sburgula.data.entity.Screening;
                    import com.sburgula.data.entity.Theatre;
                    import com.sburgula.data.entity.Ticket;
                    import com.sburgula.data.repository.MovieRepository;
                    import com.sburgula.data.repository.ScreenRepository;
                    import com.sburgula.data.repository.ScreeningRepository;
                    import com.sburgula.data.repository.TheatreRepository;
                    import com.sburgula.data.repository.TicketRepository;
                    @Service
                    public class ScreeningService {
                        private ScreeningRepository screeningRepository;
                        private MovieRepository movieRepository;
                        private TheatreRepository theatreRepository;
                        private TicketRepository ticketRepository;
                        private ScreenRepository screenRepository;
                        public ScreeningService(ScreeningRepository screeningRepository, MovieRepository movieRepository, TheatreRepository theatreRepository
                                                , TicketRepository ticketRepository, ScreenRepository screenRepository) {
                            this.screeningRepository = screeningRepository;
                            this.movieRepository = movieRepository;
                            this.theatreRepository = theatreRepository;
                            this.ticketRepository = ticketRepository;
                            this.screenRepository = screenRepository;
                        }
                        private Screening getScreening(MovieScreening movieScreening) {
                            //Browse theatres currently running the show (movie selected) in the town, including show timing by a chosen date
                            //Theatre theatre = theatreRepository.findByTheatreNameAndTheatreCity(movieScreening.getTheatreName(), movieScreening.getTheatreCity());
                            List<Theatre> theatres = theatreRepository.findTheatresByTheatreNameAndTheatreCity(movieScreening.getTheatreName(), movieScreening.getTheatreCity());
                            if (theatres == null)
                                return null;       
                            return screeningRepository.findByMovieNameAndTheatreIdAndScreeningDateAndScreeningTime(movieScreening.getMovieName(), movieScreening.getTheatreId(),
            java.sql.Date.valueOf(movieScreening.getScreeningDate()), java.sql.Time.valueOf(movieScreening.getScreeningTime()));
                        }
                        public int bookSeats(MovieScreening movieScreening, int seats) {
                            //seats -- how many the user wants to book.
                            Screening screening = getScreening(movieScreening);
                            //List<Screening> screenings = getScreening(movieScreening);
                            List<Theatre> theatres = null;
            if("PUNE".equalsIgnoreCase(movieScreening.getTheatreCity()) || "HYDERABAD".equalsIgnoreCase(movieScreening.getTheatreCity())  || movieScreening.getTheatreId()==3) {
                                theatres = theatreRepository.findTheatresByTheatreNameAndTheatreCity(movieScreening.getTheatreCity(), movieScreening.getTheatreName());             
                            }
                                for(Theatre theatre: theatres) {
            if(theatre.getTheatreCity().equals(movieScreening.getTheatreCity())){
                                        List<Ticket> tickets = ticketRepository.findByScreeningId(screening.getScreenId());
                                        for(Ticket ticket : tickets) {
                                            if(ticket.getTicketId() == 3) {
            ticket.setPrice(ticket.getPrice().divide(new BigDecimal(2)));
                                                ticketRepository.save(ticket);
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                             screening.setBookedTickets(seats);
                              screeningRepository.save(screening);
                            }
                            return getBookedSeats(movieScreening);
                        }
                    
                        public int getBookedSeats(MovieScreening movieScreening) {
                            Screening screening = getScreening(movieScreening);
                            return screening.getBookedTickets();
                        }
                        public int getTotalSeats(MovieScreening movieScreening) {
                            Screening screening = getScreening(movieScreening);
                            long screenId = screening.getScreenId();
                            return screenRepository.findByScreenId(screenId).getSeatsNum();
                        }
                        public Set<Movie> getMoviesByDate(Date date) {
                            Iterable<Screening> screenings = this.screeningRepository.findByScreeningDate(new java.sql.Date(date.getTime()));
                            Set<Movie> movies = new HashSet<>();
                            if (screenings != null) {
                                for (Screening screening : screenings) {
                                    Movie movie = movieRepository.findByMovieName(screening.getMovieName());
                                    movies.add(movie);
                                }
                            }
                    
                            return movies;
                        }
                        public List<Screening> getScreeningsByMovie(String movieName) {
                            return this.screeningRepository.findByMovieName(movieName);
                        }
                        public List<MovieScreening> getMovieScreeningsByMovie(String movieName) {
                            Iterable<Screening> screenings = this.screeningRepository.findByMovieName(movieName);
                            List<MovieScreening> movieScreenings = new ArrayList<>();
                            if (screenings != null) {
                                for (Screening screening : screenings) {
                                    MovieScreening movieScreening = new MovieScreening();
                                    Theatre theatre = theatreRepository.findByTheatreId(screening.getTheatreId());
                                    movieScreening.setMovieName(screening.getMovieName());
                                    if (theatre != null) {
            movieScreening.setTheatreId(theatre.getTheatreId());
            movieScreening.setTheatreName(theatre.getTheatreName());
            movieScreening.setTheatreCity(theatre.getTheatreCity());
                                    }
            movieScreening.setScreeningDate(screening.getScreeningDate().toString());
            movieScreening.setScreeningTime(screening.getScreeningTime().toString());
                                    movieScreenings.add(movieScreening);
                                }
                            }
                            return movieScreenings;
                        }
                    }
```

I am addign the Repository class as well...

```
                @Repository
                public interface ScreeningRepository extends CrudRepository<Screening, Long> {
                    List<Screening> findByScreeningDate(Date screeningDate);
                    List<Screening> findByMovieName(String movieName);
                    Screening findByMovieNameAndTheatreIdAndScreeningDateAndScreeningTime(String movieName, long theatreId, Date screeningDate, Time screeningTime);
                    List<Screening> getScreeningsByMovieNameScreeningDateAndScreeningTime(String movieName, Date screeningDate, Time screeningTime);
                }
```

Please find the Data Loader Class:

```
                    package com.sburgula.runner;
                    import com.sburgula.data.entity.Movie;
                    import com.sburgula.data.entity.Screen;
                    import com.sburgula.data.entity.Screening;
                    import com.sburgula.data.repository.MovieRepository;
                    import com.sburgula.data.repository.ScreenRepository;
                    import com.sburgula.data.repository.ScreeningRepository;
                    import org.jsoup.HttpStatusException;
                    import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
                    import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
                    import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
                    import org.slf4j.Logger;
                    import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
                    importorg.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
                    import org.springframework.boot.ApplicationArguments;
                    import org.springframework.boot.ApplicationRunner;
                    import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
                    import org.springframework.core.task.TaskExecutor;
                    import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
                    import org.springframework.util.ResourceUtils;
                    import java.io.*;
                    import java.sql.Date;
                    import java.sql.Time;
                    import java.util.List;
                    import java.util.Random;
                    import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;
                    @Component
                    public class DataLoader implements ApplicationRunner {
                        private MovieRepository movieRepository;
                        private ScreenRepository screenRepository;
                        private ScreeningRepository screeningRepository;
                        private final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());
                        @Autowired
                        private TaskExecutor taskExecutor;
                        public MovieRepository getMovieRepository() {
                            return movieRepository;
                        }
                        public ScreeningRepository getScreeningRepository() {
                            return screeningRepository;
                        }
                        public ScreenRepository getScreenRepository() {
                            return screenRepository;
                        }
                        @Autowired
                        public DataLoader(MovieRepository movieRepository, ScreeningRepository screeningRepository,ScreenRepository screenRepository) {
                            this.movieRepository = movieRepository;
                            this.screeningRepository = screeningRepository;
                            this.screenRepository = screenRepository;
                        }
                     private class ProcessMovie implements Runnable {
                            private String movieLine;
                            private String linkLine;
                            ProcessMovie(String movieLine, String linkLine) {
                                this.movieLine = movieLine;
                                this.linkLine = linkLine;
                            }
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                LOGGER.info(Thread.currentThread().getId() + ":" + linkLine);
                                String[] movieInfo = movieLine.split(",");
                                String movieName = "";
                                for (int i = 1; i < movieInfo.length-1; i++) {
                                    if (i == movieInfo.length-2)
                                        movieName += movieInfo[i];
                                    else
                                        movieName += movieInfo[i] + ",";
                                }
                                Movie movie = new Movie();
                                movie.setMovieId(Long.parseLong(movieInfo[0]));
                                movie.setMovieName(movieName.substring(0, movieName.indexOf('(')).trim());
                                String[] linkInfo = linkLine.split(",");
                                Document movieLensPage = null;
                                try {
                                    movieLensPage = Jsoup.connect("https://www.imdb.com/title/tt" + linkInfo[1]).get();
                                } catch (HttpStatusException e) {
                                    return;
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                               movieRepository.save(movie);
                            }
                        }
                        private void populateMovieTable() {
                            try (BufferedReader brMovies = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new ClassPathResource("movies.medium.csv").getInputStream()));
                                   BufferedReader brLinks = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new ClassPathResource("links.csv").getInputStream()))) {
                                String movieLine;
                                String linkLine;
                                brMovies.readLine();    // Skip header line
                                brLinks.readLine();     // Skip header line
                                while ((movieLine = brMovies.readLine()) != null{
                                    linkLine = brLinks.readLine();
                                    new ProcessMovie(movieLine, linkLine).run();
                                }
                            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                        private void populateScreeningsTable() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
                            for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
                                List<Screen> screens = screenRepository.findByTheatreId(i);
                                for (int j = 0; j < screens.size(); j++) {
                                    Screening screening1 = new Screening();
                                    Screening screening2 = new Screening();
                                    screening1.setTheatreId(i);
                                    screening1.setScreenId(j+1);
                                    screening2.setTheatreId(i);
                                    screening2.setScreenId(j+1);
                                    long totalMovies = movieRepository.count();
                                    Random random = new Random();
                                    long movieId1 random.nextInt((int)totalMovies)+1;
                                    Movie movie1 = null;
                                    while ((movie1 = movieRepository.findByMovieId(movieId1)) == null)
                                        movieId1 = random.nextInt((int)totalMovies)+1;
                                    long movieId2 = random.nextInt((int)totalMovies)+1;
                                    Movie movie2 = null;
                                    while ((movie2 = movieRepository.findByMovieId(movieId2)) == null)
                                        movieId2 = random.nextInt((int)totalMovies)+1;
                                    screening1.setMovieName(movie1.getMovieName());
                                    screening2.setMovieName(movie2.getMovieName());
                                    Date date1 = new Date((new java.util.Date()).getTime());
                                    Date date2 = new Date(date1.getTime()+3*24*60*60*1000);
                                    Date randomDate1 = new Date(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextLong(date1.getTime(), date2.getTime()));
                                    Date randomDate2 = new Date(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextLong(date1.getTime(), date2.getTime()));
                                    screening1.setScreeningDate(randomDate1);
                                    screening2.setScreeningDate(randomDate2);
                                    screening1.setBookedTickets(0);
                                    screening2.setBookedTickets(0);
            screening1.setScreeningTime(Time.valueOf("10:00:00"));
                                    screeningRepository.save(screening1);
                         Screening screening1Clone = (Screening)screening1.clone();
            screening1.setScreeningTime(Time.valueOf("18:00:00"));
                                    screeningRepository.save(screening1Clone);
                         if (randomDate1.getDate() != randomDate2.getDate()) {
                   screening2.setScreeningTime(Time.valueOf("10:00:00"));
                                        screeningRepository.save(screening2);
                                        Screening screening2Clone = (Screening)screening2.clone();
                   screening2.setScreeningTime(Time.valueOf("18:00:00"));
                    screeningRepository.save(screening2Clone);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                       @Override
                        public void run(ApplicationArguments applicationArguments) throws Exception {
                            populateMovieTable();
                            populateScreeningsTable();
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: Is it how I am inserting the Date parameter in the SQL Insert query....?

Comment: IS there anyone who can help me out here?  No comments since 2 days....Please help out...

Comment: Can you complete the question with the source code of your service calss. (screeningService)

Comment: I have updated the code below.  Thanks for responding.  I do want to learn what is wrong and see if I can get a solution.. Thanks.

Comment: can you share your other entity class, and `screeningRepository` as well?

Comment: I have added the screeningRepository as well.  Sorry for the delay.  But a fast response can help.....Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your repository. Your last `getScreeningsByMovieNameScreeningDateAndScreeningTime` is wrong. It should be.

```
public interface ScreeningRepository extends CrudRepository<Screening, Long> {
   List<Screening> findByScreeningDate(Date screeningDate);
   List<Screening> findByMovieName(String movieName);
   Screening findByMovieNameAndTheatreIdAndScreeningDateAndScreeningTime(String movieName, long theatreId, Date screeningDate, Time screeningTime);
   List<Screening> findByMovieNameAndScreeningDateAndScreeningTime(String movieName, Date screeningDate, Time screeningTime);
}
```

When you write complex queries I recommend writing SQL native or non native queries. [More](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71367960/spring-find-by-like-feature/71368620#71368620)

Comment: But I just realized I am not calling that method anywhere I am calling the 3rd method(findByMovieNameAndTheatreIdAndScreeningDateAndScreeningTime) in the Implementation class.  So is it because that(the getScreeningsBy....) is defined and not being called anywhere?

Comment: Just try it. Comment it out and it will work. That is why it is not working, because of the dependency injection in your service class. You try to inject a wrong repository, and that is the reason why bean creation fails.

Comment: Now I am getting another error on startup: Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'. Stopping service Tomcat. Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************
Field taskExecutor in com.sburgula.runner.DataLoader required a bean of type 'org.springframework.core.task.TaskExecutor' that could not be found.
Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.core.task.TaskExecutor' in your configuration.

Comment: Please provide your DataLoader calss, or where you use it. From this less information is it not possible to tell what is the problem. Probaly the problem is in conenction with your dependency injections.

Comment: Added the DataLoader Class

Comment: The problem is what you can read in the error message. You try to @Autowired a class that is not declared. You should create a Bean of TaskExcutor, but I don't understad why you need it when you don't even use it. You can just simply remove is.