# Spring Find By Like Feature

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have a list of entities in my code (google.com, amazon.com, etc), and I would like to have my repository find an entity when I type feed it a string with a subdomain.

So basically, what repository function do I implement so I can run something like

```
public List<ValidDomainsEntity> findByCompanyDomainLike("www.google.com");
```

and have it return the entity with google.com in its

```
String companyDomain;
```

where the companyDomain = "google.com"

So in more layman's terms: My db contains URL's without the subdomain or prefix. What query do I use in spring's repository to find that URL when I put in a URL with a subdomain

Edit: Basically how I do the spring equivalent of

```
select * from valid_domains where 'www.amazon.com' LIKE CONCAT('%', companyDomain);
```

Comment: Stripping the prefix before you make the query is probably simplest.

Comment: Tried that, there is no good way to do it.

Comment: You will have to reformat the request parameter before issuing the query i.e remove any prefix if available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write it in several ways. First option is writing a native query.

```
@Query(value = "select * from valid_domains where 'www.amazon.com' LIKE CONCAT('%', :companyDomain", nativeQuery = true);
public List<ValidDomainsEntity> myQuery(@Param("companyDomain") String companyDomain);
```

Second option is writing a simple non native Query and use your Entiry class names and fields. For this you purpose you can use `javax.persistence.EntityManager` or `@Query(value = "", nativeQuery = false)`. By default @Query is non native query, you dont have to write `nativeQuery = true`. I show also an EntityManager example.

```
@Autowired //Constructor dependency injection is more preferred instead of @Autowired
private EntityManager entityManager;

List<ValidDomain> query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT new ValidDomain(d.id, d.domainName) from ValidDomain d where 'www.amazon.com' LIKE CONCAT('%', :variableName)", ValidDomain.class).getResultList();
```

Or you can also use `EntityManager`, `entityManager.createNativeQuery()` for creating native query.